# Starting with Platform.sh - trying to get project, receiving error "The provided cwd does not exist." what does this mean?

Tags: platform

Starting with Platform.sh - trying to get project, receiving error "The provided cwd does not exist." what does this mean?

The error literally reads "**[RuntimeException]  The provided cwd does not exist.**"

No clue what that means. I run the following command in git bash:

```
platform get [id]
```

Which should get my project. But I get that error. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work at [Platform.sh](https://platform.sh).

This was a bug in the Platform.sh CLI that affected use on Windows. It has been fixed in later versions, from [v3.25.1](https://github.com/platformsh/platformsh-cli/releases/tag/v3.25.1) (the root cause was [a bug in Symfony Console](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/25447)). Sorry for the inconvenience.

Please use the [Platform.sh docs](https://docs.platform.sh) and [support](https://platform.sh/support) to get help faster.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are referring to [Platform.sh, the Continuous Deployment Cloud Hosting](https://github.com/platformsh).

As mentioned in "[platformsh-cli PR 155](https://github.com/platformsh/platformsh-cli/pull/155)":

> It is possible to run the command from inside the repository directory, but it leaves the shell in a weird state, at least when using ZSH (it reports the wrong cwd).

So make sure you did a `project:init` before the get.